# This app could not be installed at this time

Tags: ios, swift

When we integrated the gaode map SDK, we encountered a serious problem that prevented us from installing the app in simulator. I looked up the logs for the simulator. This is what is described in the log:

> Jun 26 15:17:06 LSCNM597978 com.apple.dt.Xcode[5141] : installApplication:withOptions:error:: Error Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 "This app could not be installed at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This app could not be installed at this time., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f97cd9133c0 {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=35 "Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path .../Frameworks/AMapFoundationKit.framework" UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=PackageInspectionFailed, FunctionName=-[MIBundle _validateWithError:], SourceFileLine=38, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path ....

I have tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like this is the error "Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path". Have you checked your Info.plist file?

Comment: gaode map SDK -> Google Map SDK?

Comment: its google map or gaode map?

Comment: its amap sdk ,not google map

Comment: but this framework don't have info.plist

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this specific bit `LegacyErrorString=PackageInspectionFailed`, I suspect this might happen if your product name contains non-latin characters. Try removing those non-latin characters and build again. See if that works.

Comment: My product name don't contains non-latin characters.it only happend this framework

Comment: how did you integrate the SDK into your project? Did you install the SDK through cocoapods?

Comment: I'm not integrated with cocoapods, it's imported manually.Now,I would like to ask what kind of introduction would lead him to find info in the framework

Comment: Try integrating it with cocoapods, it should work for you. They have the info for doing so.

Comment: but this project use carthage,don't use cocoapods,and the framework don't support carthage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I introduced the framework in the wrong way in my project, causing Xcode to find the framework's info.plist file